# Creating html5 page from a string stored in a database

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have an html file content stored as string in a database column. The following is how the file in the database column looks like. The whole of the above is stored in a column.

Now how do I use this to generate a page and display?  I need help.

Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="lead">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What server technology are you using? What data model?

Comment: I am using asp.net (visual studio 2013) and Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and the above string is stored in the sql column

Answer (score 1):

This could be accomplished with a Generic Handler (ashx)

```
public class GetWeb : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        // get html from SQL server
        var html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
                     <html lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
                         <head>
                             <meta charset='utf-8' />
                             <title></title>
                         </head>
                         <body>
                             <div class='lead'>
                                 <h1>Hello world</h1>
                             </div>
                         </body>
                     </html>";

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        context.Response.Write(html);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much.  Now if I call the method it asks for the HttpContext parameter and I don't know what that is. Please excuse my ignorance. This is how I implemented it:                  App_Start.GetWeb getWeb = new App_Start.GetWeb();
                getWeb.ProcessRequest(...);

Comment: @Bainn Did you add this as a `Generic Handler` or a `Class`? Visual C#-->Web-->General-->Generic Handler -- it would be navigated to like a page `http://yourserver/GetWeb.ashx` -- you will need to do logic inside the handler to determine what will load (e.g., reading from the Session or from a query string: `/GetWeb.ashx?page=home`)

Comment: I am going to try this immediately and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Next, you may want to look into Routing, so something like `http://yourserver/home` routes to `http://yourserver/GetWeb.ashx?page=home` @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202(v=vs.90).aspx